# cakePHP 3 save data in Many to Many relationship

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have Employees and Complexes in a Many to many relationship.I have used the
bake console to generate models, controllers... for Employees and Complexes tables.
My questions is : 
-Since I have in my BD The table "complexes_employees", do I have to bake also Model
and controller for this Table too or cakePHP is able to know that it contains the 
two foreign keys of Employees and Complexes.

Second question : 
-How can I save my data in this Three tables. for my app I have to save employees
per Complex .

```
// Employees Controller
public function addEmpPerComplex($id_complex){
$emp = $this->Employees->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$employee = $this->Employees->patchEntity($employee, $this->request->data, ['associated'=>['Complexes._joinData']] );
//here I need to insert the record that contains the employee data in Employees Table 
// then I need to insert in "complexes_employees" the ID of Complex sended in parametre of this function and the ID of the new Employee
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do I have to bake also Model and controller for this Table?**

No, CakePHP will use the abstract *Table* class. However, if you need extra information for this relationship, then you will need to create a **join model**. Check http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option

**How can I save my data in this Three tables?**

As long as your data has the id of a related entity, it will automatically be saved both entity and relation:

```
$data = [
    //employee data,
    'complexes' => [
        ['id' => $id_complex]
    ]
]

$this->Employees->patchEntity($employee, $data, [
    'associated' => ['Complexes']
]);

/* 
 Saves both the new Employee and the relation 
 (employeed id and complex id in complexes_employees)
*/
$this->Employees->save($employee);
```

For more information: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations

Comment: thanks a lot , No I don't have other fields in my association "complexes_employees" so no need to create model,controller for this table. For saving code I'm gonna try what you told me to do  hope it will work . Again ,thank you for your time and your help :)